# in C# How to display 1GB XML Data very fast using XMLTextReader...?

Tags: c#

I have a 1 GB XML File .By using XMLTextReader how to display total data of this file very fast.Your suggestions are valueble

Thanks ,
sivaram

Comment: Dude! you need to provide more detail than that. 1 GB! Holy crap! WTF?

Comment: Plus, *YOU* already asked this question. That's just rude.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question you already asked and got answers for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468948/in-c-what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-large-xml-size-of-1gb

Comment: Previously I asked what are the betmethods.I found some 5 methods and concluded that XMLTextReader is best.Now i want to display the data in Userinterface very fast...?Thanks..

Comment: That isn't clear in the question, so you might want to explain why you picked XMLTextReader so the readers understand the context of the question better.

Comment: WTF? Display it for what? Who in their right mind is going to read it?

Answer (score 7):

1gb.  XML File.  Those two things should never appear in the same sentence, but in case they do, realize this: Not all classes in System.XML are going to like this document.  Imagine CPU at 100% and RAM maxed out.  Consider a custom solution using the XmlReader:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XmlParsing.aspx