# Handling strings more than 2 GB

Tags: c#, xml, string, excel

I have an application where an XLS file with lots of data entered by the user is opened and the data in it is converted to XML. I have already mapped the columns in the XLS file to XML Maps. When I try to use the ExportXml method in XMLMaps, I get a string with the proper XML representation of the XLS file. I parse this string a bit and upload it to my server.

The problem is, when my XLS file is really large, the string produced for XML is over 2 GB and I get a Out of Memory exception. I understand that the limit for CLR objects is 2 GB. But in my case I need to handle this scenario. Presently I just message asking the user to send less data.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

EDIT:

This is just a jist of the operation I need to do on the generated XML.

- Remove certain fields which are not needed for the server data.
- Add something like ID numbers for each row of data.
- Modify the values of certain elements.
- Do validation on the data.

While the XMLReader stream is a good idea, I cannot perform these operations by that method. While data validation can be done by Excel itself, the other things cannot be done here.

Using XMLTextReader and XMLTextWriter and creating a custom method for each of the step is a solution I had thought of. But to go through the jist above, it requires the XML document to be gone through or processed 4 times. This is just not efficient.

Comment: Can you give an example of the content of your xml?

Comment: Edited tags to include Excel, since you're exporting from Excel.  Also removed CLR since this question doesn't have a lot to do with the specific runtime or low level code.  Feel free to edit them again or roll back if you disagree.

Comment: @Jon Egerton: Something like sales orders for the year. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: You can't chunk the content into manageable-size pieces?

Comment: When you say that you need to "remove certain fields", how much of the overall data is being removed? If you are removing a significant amount then do that in Excel before exporting to XML. That might help to keep you under 2GB

Comment: @Tim Williams - I will try chunking and let you know.

Comment: @barrowc - I remove it using the RemoveChild method. Max 3 - 4 nodes are only removed.

Answer (score 5):

If the XML is that large, then you might be able to use Export to a temporary file, rather than using ExportXML to a string - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xmlmap.export.aspx

If you then need to parse/handle the XML in C#, then for handling such large XML structures, you'll probably be better off implementing a custom  XMLReader (or XMLWriter) which works at the stream level. See this question for some similar advice - [What is the best way to parse large XML (size of 1GB) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468948/in-c-what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-large-xml-size-of-1gb)

Comment: I have added a jist of the further processing that I need to do.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for now... depends a bit on what your client is - is it Silverlight? WPF? WinForms? Command Line? One option for you might be to use some kind of data api direct into the excel spreadsheet before you do the xml work - e.g. you could use something like ADO.Net with Excel - but this does depend what your client application and its environment are

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no other way then using x64-OS and FX if you really need to hold the whole thing in RAM, but using some other way to process the data like suggested by Stuart may is the better way to go...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use "stream chaining",  i.e. you open up an input stream which reads from your excel file and an output stream that writes to your xml file. Then your conversion class/method will take the two streams as input and read sufficient data from the input stream to be able to write to the output.

Edit: very simple minimal Example

Converting from file:

```
  123
  1244125
  345345345 
  4566
  11
```

to

```
  <List>
      <ListItem>123</ListItem>
      <ListItem>1244125</ListItem>
      ...
  </List>
```

using

```
  void Convert(Stream fromStream, Stream toStream)
  {
     using(StreamReader from= new StreamReader(fromStream))
     using(StreamWriter to = new StreamWriter(toStream))
     {
        to.WriteLine("<List>");
        while(!from.EndOfStream)
        {
            string bulk = from.ReadLine(); //in this case, a single line is sufficient
            //some code to parse the bulk or clean it up, e.g. remove '\r\n' 
            to.WriteLine(string.Format("<ListItem>{0}</ListItem>", bulk));
        }
        to.WriteLine("</List>"); 
      }

  }

  Convert(File.OpenRead("source.xls"), File.OpenWrite("source.xml"));
```

Of course you could do this in much more elegent, abstract manner but this is only to show my point

Comment: Are you talking about creating my own method/class to map the excel data to the required schema and generate the xml file?

Comment: Yeah like ConvertXMLToExcel(Stream input, Stream output), you could simplify to StreamReader input and StreamWriter output. Then in your function you need to make a loop where you read sufficiently enough from the input stream to be able to write to the output stream.

Comment: I have made a few edits in the question to add more details. Kindly check it. This solution cannot be used.